# using anchot tags and href in jquery prepend and append

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to append an anchor tag into a div with id #photo. however the href contains key pair data as well as hyperlinks. What is the correct way to write this line of code.

Ideally I want the line of code to be as follows

```
 $('#photo').prepend('<a href="javascript:pixlr.edit({image:'http://mysite.com/photo    /+'photo'+', title:'+photo+', service:'express',exit:'http://mysite.com', method:'get', locktarget: 'true', target:'http://mysite.come/upload', locktitle :'true'});" id="uploadedPhotoEdit" title="click to enhance photo before sharing"></a>');
```

photo is a jquery variable which holds the name of an uploaded photo. How do you use jquery variables and use hyperlinks without hyperlinks I know it is as simple as '+nameofvariable+' but with the introduction of hyperlinks which use double quotes it becomes difficult.

Thanks

Comment: why use a "javascript:" href instead of an onclick?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the JSON object then use JSON.stringify to make that object a string. If you plan on having this be usable by a browser that does not support JSON.stringify, you will need to include the following JS file: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

```
var photo = "photo.gif";

var pixlrJson  = {
    image : 'http://mysite.com/photo/' + photo,
    title : photo,
    service : 'express',
    exit : 'http://mysite.com',
    method : 'get',
    locktarget : true,
    target : 'http://mysite.come/upload',
    locktitle : true
};

$('#photo').prepend("<a href='javascript:pixlr.edit(" + JSON.stringify(pixlrJSON) + ");' id='uploadedPhotoEdit' title='click to enhance photo before sharing'></a>");
```

If you do not like that solution you can escape quotes using a backslash.

```
var test = "This is a test string that has a \" inside of it";
```

Another alternative is to use double quotes inside of the single quoted string: